# Check it is number or not and import sys on python

Tags: python, sys, isalpha

I just want to know how can i check it is number or not in import sys situation.
and want to know Why i didn't get output "Hello" with code **A.isalpha()**

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please your code as text, not as an image; remember to format it.

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

The method `A.isalpha()` returns a boolean value `True` or `False` not a string `"True"`, you compare booleans like this

```
if A.isalpha() is True: 
    print("hello")
```

But as a `if` expects a boolean statement, the return value from `isalpha` is already good

```
if A.isalpha():
    print("hello")
```

Comment: just one more question. i don't understand the difference between == and is when i use if statement. sorry for low level question.

Comment: @JohnKang here `==` could also be used, but still with `True`, I let you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is or google *python is or ==* for mor details